# Convert a Python dataframe date column in seconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am reading a `.csv` data file using `pd.read_csv` and I get these first 5 rows from my global dataframe (containing thousands of rows):

```
    time                   id   time_offset
0   2017-12-01 21:00:00     0   -60
1   2017-12-01 21:01:00     0   -59
2   2017-12-01 21:02:00     0   -58
3   2017-12-01 21:03:00     0   -57
4   2017-12-01 21:04:00     0   -56
```

I'm not very good at manipulating dates in Python and I haven't found how to do this manipulation:

1. create in my dataframe a new `hour` column from the existing `time` column, containing only the `hours:minutes:seconds` data, which should be: `21:00:00`, `21:01:00`, `21:02:00`, etc...
2. then create another column `seconds` from the newly created `hour`, containing the number of seconds elapsed since time `0`, which should be: `75600` (calculated as 21x3600), `75601` (calculated ,as 21x3600 + 1), etc...

Any help in sorting this out would be much appreciated.

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. If you are using pandas, please remember to include the pandas tag as described in the Python tag wiki: "When using a Python variant (e.g. Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), please include it in the tags".

Comment: You don't appear to have even tried. Surely you must have some ideas, even if they don't work out?

Comment: Can we assume that `time` values are strings and you want the `hh:mm:ss` also as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
# convert `time` column to datetime (if necessary):
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])

df["hour"] = df["time"].dt.time
df["seconds"] = (
    df["time"].dt.hour * 60 * 60
    + df["time"].dt.minute * 60
    + df["time"].dt.second
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 time  id  time_offset      hour  seconds
0 2017-12-01 21:00:00   0          -60  21:00:00    75600
1 2017-12-01 21:01:00   0          -59  21:01:00    75660
2 2017-12-01 21:02:00   0          -58  21:02:00    75720
3 2017-12-01 21:03:00   0          -57  21:03:00    75780
4 2017-12-01 21:04:00   0          -56  21:04:00    75840
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignment of the datetime series as the index is typically useful. Use pd.to_datetime() converts it to a usable format.

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.drop('time',axis=1)
```

1. can use the strftime function - https://strftime.org/

```py
df['time'] = df.index.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

2. since `df.index[0]` is the very first time you can subtract and use `.seconds` attribute:

```py
df['seconds since'] = (df.index = df.index[0]).seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'time': {0: '2017-12-01 21:00:00', 1: '2017-12-01 21:01:00', 2: '2017-12-01 21:02:00', 
                 3: '2017-12-01 21:03:00', 4: '2017-12-01 21:04:00'}, 
        'id': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 
        'time_offset': {0: -60, 1: -59, 2: -58, 3: -57, 4: -56}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
  time                   id   time_offset
0   2017-12-01 21:00:00     0   -60
1   2017-12-01 21:01:00     0   -59
2   2017-12-01 21:02:00     0   -58
3   2017-12-01 21:03:00     0   -57
4   2017-12-01 21:04:00     0   -56
```

**Code**

make timedelta and use `dt.total_seconds()`. In the case of example, since time column is object, it can be converted to timedelta in the following way.

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].str.split(' ').str[1])
```

you can convert timedelta to second by using `dt.total_seconds()`

```
s = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].str.split(' ').str[1]).dt.total_seconds()
```

`s`

```
0    75600.0
1    75660.0
2    75720.0
3    75780.0
4    75840.0
Name: time, dtype: float64
```